# Who wrote the songs for the special edition of Return of the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, music

In the special edition of *Return of the Jedi*, various changes were made to the film, with (in my opinion) some being positive and some negative. One, or should I say two, of the changes is the new songs to replace old songs. I am talking about "Jedi Rocks" replacing "Lapti Nek" (I think) and "Yub Nub" being replaced by a new end celebration song (which I don't consider that bad, honestly). Who wrote these songs? I'm assuming John Williams didn't write "Jedi Rocks," but did he write the end celebration song?

Answer (score 2):

The [new song](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Victory_Celebration) shown during the Endor victory celebration was indeed composed by John Williams and performed, as usual, by the London Symphony Orchestra.

"Jedi Rocks" was [written by Jerry Hay](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Rocks/Legends).